# android ImageView setPadding has no effect

Tags: android, imageview, padding

I am trying to set padding of an ImageView. My code is below

```
private void createEpisodeView() {
    float scale = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int padding = (int) (PADDING * scale + 0.5f);

    rlItemsRoot = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_items_root);

    for (int i = 0; i < GameLevels.TOTAL_EPISODES; i++) {
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);

        iv.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);          
        iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_small);

        rlItemsRoot.addView(iv);
    }

}
```

But it has no effect. but when I set this in XML it looks fine.

Comment: padding is default expressed in pixels when we are dynamically setting that.. In xml r u using the same values in px or dip

Comment: I am using dip in XML and here I am converting pix into DIP. and 5 constant is to cancel effect of conversion to int. i.e 0.7 is 0 in int but if you add 0.5 then it won't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A you noticed yourself you are using

```
iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_small);
```

This will set the Background for the ImageView. The Background Image will fill the whole view because it is behind all the content in the View.

Use

```
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_small);
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad I did not need do unnecessary linearlayout wrapper around imageview to get padding!

Answer (score 4):

Rather than setting

```
iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_small);
```

set

```
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_small);
```

and problem solved :)

If any body knows the reason please reply.

Comment: Your padding is lost when you set the background.  You have to `setPadding(..)` after you set the background, not before.  This is pointed out in the documentation for `setBackgroundDrawable(..)` but Google neglects to mention it for `setBackgroundResource(..)`.